# Why doesn't the value of the boolean expression change? (Java)

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, boolean, expression

The following is the code that I'm asking about:

```
int price = 0;
boolean isFree = (price == 0);

if (isFree) {
     price = 10;
     if (isFree)
         System.out.println("one");
     else
         System.out.println("two");
}
```

So I just wanna know why the `isFree` variable remains true while the price variable changes to 10. In other words why does the price variable switch to 10 without affecting the boolean expression?

Comment: The result of `price == 0` results in a *one time* assignment to `isFree`. When the value of price changes, it doesn't affect `isFree`. Java doesn't work like what you expect (I'm not sure what language does like this)

Comment: In Java, variables only change when you assign a value to them, they don't magically change at any other time.  There are languages where you can write what you expect however this only happens by making `isFree` a method/function, not a value.

Answer (score 1):

After initialized by `boolean isFree = (price == 0);`, the `isFree` variable is determined to be `true`.

it will not be changed even though the `price` is changed, unless you change it explicitly(like calling  `boolean isFree = (price == 0);` again).

Answer (score 1):

Because the isFree variable had its value set once when you defined it. If you want the isFree variable to have another value, you need to set it.

You could change your definition of isFree into a method:

```
private boolean isFree(int price) {
    return price == 0;
}
```

Then any time you want to know if the price is free, you can call the `isFree` method:

```
int price = 0;

if (isFree(price)) {

    price = 10;

    if (isFree(price))
        System.out.println("one");
    else
        System.out.println("two");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It stays the same because you don't check the boolean variable again after comparing it the first time. If you had another

```
isFree = (price == 0);
```

after checking and re-assigning price to 10, then it would be false.

Answer (score 0):

By using two isFree statements you are basically cancelling out the condition thus making it true (static) and not checking the new condition which is dynamic.

```
int price = 0;

boolean isFree = (price == 0);

if (isFree){
 price = 10;
 System.out.println("one");
}
else{
 System.out.println("two");
}
```